# What is the Best wash or glaze for bread when trying to achieve a crunchy crust on Rolls

Tags: bread, glaze

i would like to know if there is a way to get a crunchy yet golden glaze on Buns/rolls... kind of like bread you would get out of a dutch oven

Comment: What kind of bread are you making? There's no need to wash or glaze on regular bread if you want it crunchy.

Comment: I am making everything from braided knots to dinner rolls...

Comment: I also make other breads...multi grain with seeds on the top... foccassias... ciabattas...etc... i know most breads to not get glazed/washed

Comment: Hey, Tarus, you need to provide a LOT more information in order for us to answer your question.  Mostly, you need to define what "works best" means; what are your criteria and what results do you hope to achieve?   SeasonedAdvice is not a discussion site, to asking for "experiences and opinions" is off-topic, see: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: There is no magic bullet that will work with all of types of breads. As per comment above, SE is to solve problems, not to share experiences or opinions. If you can edit your question to make it a specific problem, that's better.

Comment: got it ... thanks... will re-phrase the question

Comment: You are asking specifically about washes, so not a duplicate, but the real solution to your problem: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1535/techniques-to-get-a-nice-golden-brown-crust-on-bread?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

You may have to compromise a bit here, I am assuming you want both a shiny and crunchy finish to your rolls.

Traditionally, the crunch comes from a longer period in the heating oven with lid removed from the Dutch oven to crisp-up the outer layer. A different technique is used with baguettes, where they are sprayed with fine mist at 5 minute intervals over a total cooking time of 15 minutes. Both of these methods will give an excellent crunch, although the final finish will be dull.

An egg or milk wash will give a lovely final sheen to your rolls, but in my experience this prevents the development of a really crispy crust if you use a whole beaten egg. Apparently, just using the egg white diluted with water will achieve more crunch, but I doubt if it will be as intense as the traditional DO or spray method.

https://www.thespruceeats.com/egg-wash-yeast-breads-rolls-3057783

Comment: okay... thanks for the help.... basically what i came to but was wondering if there was something i was missing...